# Authenticate same user in multiple firebase projects in web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-oauth

I am developing a website. I hosted my website to Project-A and need to get the FireStore data from another firebase project(Project-B). The sample code I wrote in my website to get the data from Project-B

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var primaryAppConfig = {
       apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
       authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
       databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
       storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    }; // Project-A configuration

    var secondaryAppConfig = {
       apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
       authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
       databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
       storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    }; // Project-B configuration

    var primary = firebase.initializeApp(primaryAppConfig);
    var secondary = firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary"); 

    var db1 = primary.firestore();
    var db2 = secondary.firestore();

    // Some code to get the data from Project-A and I got the result.
    db1.collection('sample').get().then(snap => {
       size = snap.size;
       console.log("No.ofUsers",size); //Got result

    });

    // Some code to get the data from Project-B. And here, I am getting error like Error: Missing or insufficient permissions. Lack of permissions from Project-B.

    db2.collection('sample').get().then(snap => {
      var size = snap.size;
      console.log("TotalSample",size);
    }); 

</script>
```

So that I need to authenticate the user in Project-B also. For that I wrote the below code to login into my webiste

```
function signInUser() {
    var emailelement = document.getElementById("email");
    var passwordelement = document.getElementById("password");
    if (emailelement != null){
        var email = emailelement.value;         
    }
    if (passwordelement != null){
        var password = passwordelement.value;           
    }

    primary.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {

        console.log("Logged into secondary");
        var user = primary.auth().currentUser;
        console.log(user.uid); // It showing Project-A UID

        secondary.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {

        console.log("Logged into primary");
        var user = secondary.auth().currentUser;
        console.log(user.uid); // It showing Project-B UID

        }).catch(function(error) {
           // Handle Errors here.
           var errorCode = error.code;
           var errorMessage = error.message;

           if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                 alert('Wrong password.');
           } else {
                 alert(errorMessage);
           }

         });

    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...

      if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
            alert('Wrong password.');
      } else {
            alert(errorMessage);
      }

    });
    }
```

By the above signInUser() function the user is successfully authenticated in both projects and getting the FireStore in home.html page itself after login. But I need to get the data in home.html page(so many pages in my web expect login). What I have to do in home.html page to get the current user.

//  By this user logged into both projects at a time with same credentials but with different UIDs.

Now the problem is After the authentication I need to navigate to another page using

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {

            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            if(user != null){
                console.log(user.uid); // In auth state overall it showing the Project-B UID
                window.location = 'home.html';
            }       
        } else {
        // User is signed out.
        }
    });
```

In my home.html page the it showing the current user is null

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

              var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; // it showing null   
                if(!user)
                {
                  console.log("SignOut");
                  window.location='/';
                }
                else
                {    
                  console.log(user.uid);
                }
            });
```

I need to clarify one thing. By using above signInUser() function in login.html user authenticated in both projects and I getting the data from both projects in login.html page. Actually I need to get the data in home.html page after login. But in this it showing the current user is null. I configure both projects in home.html page also like above.

Please help me out. I stopped at this point. I am new to Firebase.

In Project-B the database rules are like

```
service cloud.firestore
{
  match /databases/{database}/documents
  {
    match /sample/ {AuthId=**}
    {
       allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not checking the result `secondary.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential`. Are you sure that succeeds?

Comment: Well I am not sure sir. Yesterday I changed my login method to signInWithEmailAndPassword instead of Google Sign-in. I will update my above code in signInUser() method sir.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the game, but this is for anyone who stumbles upon this in the future.

The problem, in this case, is that you are mixing up 2 different needs: The need to authenticate a user, and the need to access a resource on a different system. The former is an interaction between a user whereas the latter is between 2 systems. Still, you are using the same set of credentials. An easy solution would be to create a set of credentials for system-to-system communication. That way you can instantiate the object to access to the resources on system B at any given time, without depending on the user credentials.

Comment: This sounds nice, but how is it done in Firebase?